# ActiveMQ with .NET

Tags: push-notification, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to create a C# program using `ActiveMQ`.

The main goal here is to experiment how to use ActiveMQ to send push messages to a client from a server which is supposed to be the message broker using the pub/sub pattern. The clients are web clients which are implemented with React.

There's an official link which suppose to have .NET examples of using `ActiveMQ`:

https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/documentation#providers

What is the difference between the providers listed? What provider do I need to use in order to achieve my goal listed above? Is using this method means using ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: Both ActiveMQ 5.x and ActiveMQ Artemis support AMQP and STOMP which both have C# client implementations you could use for this purpose. NMS is a JMS-style API for C# with multiple "providers" which implement the API on top of different messaging protocols (e.g. OpenWire, AMQP, STOMP, etc.).

Comment: @JustinBertram So what do I need to use if my clients are implemented with React?

Answer (score 0):

The [Openwire](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/providers/activemq/downloads/) based NMS client (NMS.ActiveMQ) speaks a protocol that supports most JMS style behaviours and is interoperable on both ActiveMQ 5.x and the more actively developed ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: So what do I need to use in my case when the broker is implemented with C#, and the clients with React?

Comment: I have no idea since I don't work with any brokers written in C# and NMS is not based on React.